# How can I load all music files from external storage on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to read all songs from external storage using contentResolver?.query(), but every time I run app my query is empty. It just goes from if(resultSet.moveToFirst()) to resultSet?.close(). Here is my code and debug screen below:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tracks_tab, container, false)

    permissionSetup()


    val uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0"
    val projection = arrayOf<String>(
        MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,
        MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST
    )


    val resultSet : Cursor? = activity?.applicationContext?.contentResolver?.query(uri, projection, selection, null, null)
    if (resultSet != null) {
        if(resultSet.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                val url = resultSet.getString(0)
                val artist = resultSet.getString(1)
                val title = resultSet.getString(2)

                listSong.add(SongInfo(title, artist, url))
            } while (resultSet.moveToNext())
        }
    }
    resultSet?.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyGMn.png)

> If it's important I'm writing in a tabFragment and my emulator device is Pixel 4XL with Android 11.0 API 30. Please, help me, I already tried everything I can find.

Comment: `using contentResolver?.query()` ? You should tell who you want to query to begin with. The tool you use to obtain information is less relevant then to know from wich provider you want some info.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple library! I've tested it with Android 11 works totally fine!!!

https://github.com/CodeBoy722/MediaFacer